# HTML input[type=range] does not change appearance even tho it receives value-change

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, howler.js

I am making a song-player with Howler.js and Javascript/JQuery.

I have an input[type=range] which displays the progress of the song:

```
<input class="duration" type="range" value="0">
```

There is a function that executes when the song is played:

```
onplay: function() {
    setInterval(function(){
        $('#everytime_we_touch .duration').attr('value', everytime_we_touch.seek());
    },1000);
}
```

This does work and the progress on the input[type=range] visibly changes. However, when I click on the input[type=range] manually, the value-attribute inside of the input[type=range] still changes, but  visibly it is stuck. I use this method for manually changing the song-progress:

```
$('input[type=range].duration').on('input', function () {
    let howl_name = $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
    let duration_value = this.value;
    eval(howl_name + '.seek(' + duration_value + ')');
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may want to use `.val()` instead of `.attr()` for an Input element. Also what is the Range set for `min` and `max`? Also you may want to check what `everytime_we_touch.seek()` is returning.

Comment: Also, `onplay` event, in my mind, would only be triggered once and the seek would one value. The other example is triggered by the `input` event, so it's updating upon an event action.

Comment: ```min``` is not defined (so default).
```max```:

onload: function() {
 $('#everytime_we_touch .duration').attr('max', everytime_we_touch.duration());
}

Imma try .val() now

Comment: WOW! Using .val() instead of .attr() was the answer!

Comment: I have the same problem but I am not using JQuery. I use mySlider.setAttribute('value', newVal) which changes the value but the thumb doesn't move. This only happens after the thumb or track has been clicked. Any idea why or how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider the following example. This uses `.val()` instead of `.attr()` and will have better results.

```js
$(function() {
  var timer;
  var start;

  function updateDuration(n) {
    $(".current").val(n);
    $(".duration").val(n);
  }

  $(".psudeo-player button").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    start = new Date().getSeconds();
    timer = setInterval(function() {
      var t = Math.floor(new Date().getSeconds() - start);
      updateDuration(t);
      if (t >= parseInt($(".duration")[0].max)) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        $(this).show();
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```css
.psudeo-player {
  background-color: #555;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  width: 480px;
  height: 340px;
  position: relative;
}

.psudeo-player button {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 9px);
  left: calc(50% - 30px);
}

.current {
  width: 2em;
}

.duration {
  width: 430px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="psudeo-player">
  <button>Play</button>
</div>
<input type="text" class="current" value="0" disabled><input class="duration" min="0" max="20" type="range" value="0">
```

Comment: Any idea why val() works better than attr()? I have the same problem as the OP but I am not using JQuery and I'm looking for a solution with plain js.

Comment: @MarkM There are seeking different things. `.val()` gets the Value from an Input Element. `.attr()` get an element attribute. For example, you can have `<input type="text">` with no Value attribute, yet the element does have a value. So `.attr()` would fail in getting the value in this case.

Comment: Great, thanks! You are right, when I changed `slider.setAttribute('value', pos);` to `slider.value = pos;` it works as expected.